# despite installing php 7.3, version is still php 7.2

Tags: php, 19.04

I installed php7.3 on Ubuntu 19.04 but it seems like the old binary is still in place. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ apt search php7.3
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
php7.3-common/now 7.3.4-1+ubuntu19.04.1+deb.sury.org+3 amd64 [installed,local]
  documentation, examples and common module for PHP
$ php --version
PHP 7.2.17-1+ubuntu19.04.1+deb.sury.org+3 (cli) (built: Apr 10 2019 10:52:05) ( NTS )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'oh. I had removed the PPA and not installed the php7.3-cli package before. Adding the Ondrej Sury PPA back and installing php7.3-cli solved it.

Comment: Why do you remove the PPA? You won't get bugfix/security updates then.

Comment: I was under the impression that php7.3 would come with Ubuntu and that Ubuntu would take care of updates to its distribution. But I thought wrong. Ubuntu Disco Dingo's php version is 7.2